# How user can change their password after using the hash password and salt?

Tags: php, passwords, salt

I am trying to make a website secure by using a hashed pasword and salt. I successfully implement it. But if users want to change their password it becomes difficult. How can I recode the change password I have so as to support hashedpassword and salt that I just implemented?

**This is my changepassword form - change_password.php**

```
 <form  method="post" id="change_password" class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Current Password</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>"  placeholder="Current Password">
                                            <input type="password" id="current_password" name="current_password"  placeholder="Current Password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">New Password</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password" placeholder="New Password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Re-type Password</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="password" id="retype_password" name="retype_password" placeholder="Re-type Password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <div class="controls">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-save"></i> Save</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

**This is my jQuery script**

```
<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#change_password").submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                        var password = jQuery('#password').val();
                        var current_password = jQuery('#current_password').val();
                        var new_password = jQuery('#new_password').val();
                        var retype_password = jQuery('#retype_password').val();
                        if (password != current_password)
                        {
                        $.jGrowl("Password does not match with your current password  ", { header: 'Change Password Failed' });
                        }else if  (new_password != retype_password){
                        $.jGrowl("Password does not match with your new password  ", { header: 'Change Password Failed' });
                        }else if ((password == current_password) && (new_password == retype_password)){
                    var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "update_password.php",
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(html){

                        $.jGrowl("Your password is successfully change", { header: 'Change Password Success' });
                        var delay = 2000;
                            setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'dashboard_teacher.php'  }, delay);  

                        }


                    });

                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
```

**This is my update_password.php**

```
<?php
 include('dbcon.php');
 include('session.php');
 $new_password  = $_POST['new_password'];
 mysql_query("update admins set password = '$new_password' where admins_id = '$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
```

**This is my login.php**

```
$query = "select * from admins where username = '$usernameVal';";

     $resultSet = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                           if(@mysqli_num_rows($resultSet) > 0){
                           //check noraml user salt and pass
                           //echo "noraml";

 $saltQuery = "select salt from admins where username = '$usernameVal';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$saltQuery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$salt = $row['salt'];

$saltedPW =  $escapedPW . $salt;

$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

 $query = "select * from admins where username = '$usernameVal' 
and password = '$hashedPW' ";

                            $resultSet = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                           if(@mysqli_num_rows($resultSet) > 0){
                               $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet);
                               echo "your username and  password is correct";
                               session_start();
                               $_SESSION["id"]=$row["admins_id"];

header("location:group/dashboard_teacher.php");
}
else
{
echo "your username or password is incorrect";
}

}

}
?>
```

Comment: There does not seem to be a specific question here. What problem are you coming up against?

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code anyway, so it is possible that all of your accounts could be hacked regardless of your hashing and salting.